# Elastic search filter value like "123-325-23243" during aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic search query when I try to aggregate, I have value like `1234-3245-34234-2342` it just returns with key: `1234`

Is there any possibility in mentionings the property type or regular expression in it

Some more explanation :

```
"aggregations": { "myagg": { "terms": { "field": "did", "size": 50 } } }
```

When I try it on the data the values are like `ABC-CDEF-DEFG` and after running the script it is not able aggregate it. It shows the key only to be `ABC` and

```
"key" : "ABC", "doc_count" : 24069
```

It can't take the entire key like `ABC-DEF-GHI-fhho`

Comment: Can you provide us a bit more information about your problem? What you've tried till now?

Comment: Yes..  "aggregations": {
    "myagg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "did",
        "size": 50
      }
    }
  } WHen i try it on the data .. The values are like "ABC-CDEF-DEFG" and after running the script it is not able aggregate it..It shows the key only to be "ABC" and "key" : "ABC",
        "doc_count" : 24069 .. It cant take the entire key like "ABC-DEF-GHI-fhho"

Comment: Add these information in your post, that will be very useful for the users that faces the same problem and also for us in order to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Check your mapping, I expect you did not do anything for the mapping. That is when you can the standard analyzer for strings. The standard analyser brakes up at the "-", that is why you get the term you mentioned. Make the field not_analyzed and you should get better results.

Answer (score 0):

When i use field.raw that fixes the issue...https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/364

Comment: That's because it's `not_analyzed` which doesn't break up your value. It's the right answer (to yourself, gratulations!). Please don't forget to accept your own answer!